# How can i determine PostBack value in window.onunload?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In our project we are deleting something after the user left the page. We are using window.unload event for doing this.

```
window.onunload = function() {
  // delete something
}
```

We are generally using buttons, linkbuttons..etc in UpdatePanel so we hadn't needed to check Page.IsPostBack property.

Today we realized that we used some buttons out of UpdatePanel and this situation had produced some errors. After that we decided to change our method, defined a global variable (var _isPostBack = false), at the top of the our page and:

```
window.onunload = function() {
  if (_isPostBack) {
    _isPostBack = false;
    return;
  }

  // delete something
}
```

Altought i set the g_isPostBack in Page_Load, g_isPostBack didn't change. I tried "RegisterClientScriptBlock", "RegisterOnSubmitStatement" and "RegisterStartupScript" methods. Register methods were called before the onunload event but _isPostBack was set after onunload event had triggered...

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
  Control c = MyClass.GetPostBackControl(this);
  bool inUpdatePanel = ControlParentForUpdatePanel(c);

  if (!inUpdatePanel)
  {
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "_isPostBack = true;", true);
  }
}
```

Is there anyone to help me?

Comment: Is variable "g_isPostback" or just "_isPostback"?

Comment: sory my fault... i wrote them wrong. all of them are "_isPostBack".

Comment: I am not sure that onunload method is called on ajax posts.

Comment: if postback element is out of the updatepanel, onunload method is called on ajax posts...

Comment: and no updatepanel was triggered by this element...

Comment: Please be sure that your code behind registration works. For example; ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Code behind registration is OK');_isPostBack = true;", true);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's the trick...

if you add onsubmit attribute to your form tag:

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit="return yourPostBack()">
```

and than write your own function:

```
function yourPostBack()
{
  _isPostBack = true;
  return true;
}
```

and finally in the page load:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "_isPostBack = false;", true);
}
```

with this method you can understand that it is postback or not, in window.onunload

Answer (score 0):

I hope i am on the right track here,

As i understand, 
the OnUnload() is ClientSide,
and therefore you don't have the server objects
what you can do... is save the value in a hidden field.

As i am used to PHP you can even embed the value in a Javascript variable
Dont know if this applys to ASP.NET:

```
<script language="javascript">
var MyServerVariable = "<?PHP echo MyServerVariable ?>"
if(MyServerVariable == "Blah...")
{
}
</script>
```

translates to

```
<script language="javascript">
var MyServerVariable = "VALUE"
if(MyServerVariable == "Blah...")
{
}
</script>
```

But same thing can be done with <asp:Label /> , i am sure...

Comment: yes i can embed the server value in javascript but if i implement "<%= IsPostBack%>" in Asp.NET, it is always false. IsPostBack value is always false, while pages first load...

Comment: <script>var pb = <asp:Label ... /> </script> ?