# Browser Close event in C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

Tell me the steps to capture the browser close event in asp.net c#. I
developed one web application, that user enter his username and
password, i update the status column to Active". If i logout, i update
the status column to "Inactive". Suppose if i close the browser ,
without clicking the logout button, i need to update the column to
"Inactive". Kindly tell me the steps how to update the column to
"Inactive" when i close the browser window.

Comment: Do not quote your entire post, I edited it so it was not a giant quote block.

Comment: Look into `onunload` and `onbeforeunload`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reliably do this - you must have some server-side logic to manage 'stale' logins that timeout due to inactivity and reset the appropriate column(s), either using some website events or a service or similar.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with ASP.NET specifically, it's the nature of the Internet over HTTP (and other stateless protocols).

Comment: What i do for that?can u give me a idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript

```
window.onbeforeunload
```

Take a look at this https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134123/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/100604-1.shtml

Apart from that I have to agree with Grant Thomas answer.

Comment: i tested already that method fired every post back,i need when the user click browser close button .then i need to update the column field

Comment: Chandran take a look at this method [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9020148/2311295)